# what just these code do "os.chdir("..")"?

Tags: python-3.x

I saw these code

```
open(new_user + ".database", "a")
        with open(new_user + ".database", "w") as f:
            f.write(encrypted)
        os.chdir("..")
        os.chdir("..")
```

And don't know exactly what does this do

```
os.chdir("..")
```

Comment: in the file system there are 2 special names for folder, those are "." and "..", "." represent the current folder you're in, and ".." represent the parent folder of that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.chdir` is used to change the current working directory to the specified directory which it takes as the argument (in your case, it is `..` which means parent directory).

More details here;
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-chdir-method/

Comment: If I import a module, call one of its functions which calls `os.chdir`, and then run another import, what namespace am I importing from? Has it changed due to this change of working directory?

Answer (score 1):

You can ask it:

```
import os
help(os.chdir)
```

or you can find out by looking at the [Python standard library documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os-file-dir)

It will tell you that it changes the current working directory - basically, your current position in the filesystem.